# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13

Tags: java

I'm trying to use an array to deal a Bridge hand and then have it sorted by suits. The program deals all 13 cards, but then I get the error,

```
"Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13 
at DeckStuff.main(DeckStuff.java:29)"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Card.shuffleDeck();

    Card.dumpCards();

    Card[] bridgeHand = new Card[13];

    for (int i = 0; i < bridgeHand.length; i++) {
        bridgeHand[i] = Card.dealCard();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < bridgeHand.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(bridgeHand[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();

    Card.sortHand(bridgeHand);

    String[] suit = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};

    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        String s = suit[i].substring(0,1);
        System.out.print("\n" + s + ": ");

        while (bridgeHand[j].getCardSuitName().equals(suit[i])) {
            System.out.print(bridgeHand[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: You should indicate which line "29" is in the future; because you aren't posting the whole class, it's tough for us to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

Your `j` was not being reset, and the `while` loop stops as soon as it encounters a wrong suited card, which is not correct since you want to go over all of them but only print the correctly suited cards.

try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    String s = suit[i].substring(0,1);
    System.out.print("\n" + s + ": ");

    for(int j = 0; j < bridgeHand.length; j++) {
        if (bridgeHand[j].getCardSuitName().equals(suit[i])) {
            System.out.print(bridgeHand[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you build it in for me, when I reset j to 0 inside the for loop it only deals "spades" and nothing else.

Comment: @user2317612 You can click the checkbox by my answer and it will mark it as accepted. It lets others know that this solves the problem and gives me some points.

Answer (score 3):

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13

This means you're accessing the array out of bounds. You are giving it an index value of 13. I haven't even read your code yet, but I'm guessing this is an off-by-one error.

...reading...

Yep. You're constantly incrementing j. The error message gives you a line number as well.

at DeckStuff.main(DeckStuff.java:29)"

This means the error is at line 29 in file DeckStuff.java